# Eliminar fila de la base de datos asociada con otra tabla - laravel (eliminar en cascada)

Tags: php, laravel, sql, datos

Primero que nada, mi objetivo es limpiar mi base de datos mensualmente, para ello estoy haciendo esto en un job

Tengo 5 tablas en mi base de datos

```
mail_task_mail_message => viene de la misma clase MailTask
mail_tasks => MailTask (class)
mail_messages => MailMessage (class)
meos => Meo (class)
mail_recipients => MailRecipient (class)
```

Estoy tratando de eliminar filas de una tabla con sus asociaciones primero, para esto necesito eliminar la asociación que pertenece a cada fila

ejemplo

La clase `MailTask` tiene una tabla llamada `mail_tasks` y está asociada con la clase `MailMessage`, la tabla asociada es `mail_task_mail_message`

```
public function mailMessages()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(MailMessage::class, 'mail_task_mail_message', 'mail_task_id', 'mail_message_id')
        ->withPivot('type', 'description', 'value')
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Intenté con un foreach, solo con el primer paso para el propósito, pero creo que no es correcto, aparentemente debería usar una cascada, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

estas son las asociaciones que tienen las tablas

> mail_messages no recibe datos de ninguna tabla

> "mail_task_mail_message" tiene una asociación con la tabla "mail_tasks"
> a través de la columna "mail_task_id" y también tiene otra asociación
> con la tabla mail_messages a través de la columna "mail_message_id"

[image: tabla "hijo"]

> y la tabla "mail_tasks" tiene una asociación a través de la columna
> "meo_id" con el id de la tabla "meos"

tabla mail taks[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego viene aún más grande con la tabla "meos"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda solo con el primer número, creo que no lo estoy haciendo de la manera correcta con mi simple foreach

```
public function handle()
        {
            $mailTasks = MailTask::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
            $see = $mailTasks;
            foreach ($mailTasks as $mailTask){
                $mailTaskId = $mailTask->id;
                MailTask::with('mailMessages')->from('mail_task_mail_message')->where('mail_task_id', '=', $mailTaskId)->forceDelete();
            }
    }
```

esta es la migración de mail_task_mail_message

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('mail_task_mail_message', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedInteger('type');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->decimal('value', 16, 2);
            $table->foreignId('mail_task_id')->constrained('mail_tasks')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('mail_message_id')->constrained('mail_messages')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta es algo extensa y poco clAra, puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: @BetaM estoy intentando hacer un delete, de una fila completa en la base de datos y también eliminar sus asociaciones

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes utilizar son los [eventos](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events) de Eloquent.

Cuando se detecte un evento de eliminación dicho evento se disparará y podrás ejecutar ciertas acciones.

1. Necesito eliminar Meo donde "deleted_all" no sea nulo y eliminar primero las asociaciones con MailRecipients.

En tu Modelo `Meo.php` debes agregar el método `booted` para utilizar el evento `deleting`.

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::deleting(function ($meo) {
        //MailRecipients::where('meo_id', $meo->id)->forceDelete();
        $meo->mailRecipients()->forceDelete();
    });
}
```

La lógica de esto se traduce de la siguiente manera:

Cuando intentes eliminar un registro de tu tabla `Meo`, primero eliminará todos los registros relacionados que tenga en la tabla `MailRecipients`, esto debido a que antes de eliminar se ejecutará el evento.

---

**Por otro lado:**

Por la manera en la que escribiste tu código pienso que lo que quieres es simplemente **limpiar tu base de datos**, ya que siempre obtienes todos los registros sin filtro específico.

Por lo que tu único problema es el **orden** de tus consultas. Debes analizar qué tabla depende de la otra y, dependiendo de eso, efectuar la eliminación en orden.

```
$mailTask = MailTask::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
$mailTask->forceDelete();

$meo = Meo::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
$meo->forceDelete();

// No mostraste nada respecto a la tabla MailMessage
$mailMessage = MailMessage::query()->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
$mailMessage->forceDelete();
```

En ese orden debería ejecutarse todo con normalidad ya que MailTask es una tabla independiente, no tiene ningún `hijo`. La lógica es eliminar a los hijos primero, luego a los padres.

Comment: MailMessage va solita, no tiene conexión con ninguna, voy a probar, gracias!

Comment: sí quiero limpiar mensualmente mi base de datos de todos los elementos eliminados, pero se me complica por el tema de los heredados, actualizo la pregunta

Comment: hola @L. Flor, he actualizado la pregunta, además de haber añadido una tabla faltante, la respuesta a todo esto sigue siendo similar a la tuya?